# Android java - Correct way of onActivityResult() with local service working?

Tags: java, android, service, onactivityresult

I have a local service and I let my program go further in onServiceConnected method :

```
intentaudio=new Intent(this,AudioService.class);
    sConn=new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override 
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            bound=false; 
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            audioService = ((AudioService.MyBinder) binder).getService();
            bound = true;
body(); //this is the main code for the Activity - I moved it to separate method
        }
    };

  startService(intentaudio);
  bindService(intentaudio, sConn, 0);
```

so, during this Activity I start another one :

```
  intent=new Intent(mContext,Prayer.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent,1);
```

and second Activity goes well, but.. if I go back - I don't know what to do.

in onActivityResult - I need service to connect back, so I should do another

`sConn=new ServiceConnection() {`... etc, but how can I just let the Activity go on connected to service? As you see, the whole Activity is in  `onServiceConnected` method so it can interact with service immideately. So.. I just don't know what to do.

Please help!

Answer (score -1):

utilise onpause onrestart onresume..

Comment: sry for not clear answer from me, my intention is use restart your service when your coming back to the previous activity by using onrestart or re create activity..

Comment: okay, look.. This activity goes inside onServiceConnected method, second Activity also works inside onServiceConnected method. So when I go back to onActivityResult method - how do I properly restart service connection?

Comment: you mean it can be bound in both Activities at the same time?

Comment: if you are starting service application level it won't occur where ever you are, if activity level we have to handle the service in different way..